# UITabBarController not changing the color of the 'more' button icons

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBar for my app. Since it has too many views to display all at once it has the 'More' button that drops down a tableView that displays the rest of the views. I am attempting to change the color of the icons to match the rest of them at the bottom as for some reason the default values are gray for the bottom icons and blue for the icons inside the more view. I managed to get it to work by adding in the line:

`self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.view.tintColor = .grayColor()`

I added this line inside the first tab's view controller in the `viewDidLoad` function. Again, this worked, but it didn't feel right to put it there so I made a `UITabBarController` and put the line in the `viewDidLoad` of that controller. I then connected the controller through storyboard with the class field in the Custom Class section of the identity inspector. With it done this way the TabBar no longer uses it and the icons turn back to blue.

My question is: Should I have kept that line in the first viewController loaded? Or should I put that line somewhere else entirely?

First Image: showing the bottom icons on the tabBar, the currently selected icon is black, the others are gray.
[image]

Second Image: This shows the whole screen with the tabbar at the bottom and the more page selected, as you can see, the icons are blue, I want to change these to gray.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Create a new class that extends UITabBarController and then instead of using `self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.view.tintColor = .grayColor()`

use
`self.moreNavigationController.view.tintColor = .grayColor()`

Example:

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.moreNavigationController.view.tintColor = .grayColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Though this will affect all tab bars the View Controller can access (I believe), so be careful. It should however change the tab bar whether it's a UITabBar or a UITabBarController.

Comment: No, that only changes the color of the bottom icons, I am changing the icons in the 'more' view

Comment: Also, that only seems to affect the currently selected icon

Comment: Hm do you think you could post a screenshot? I don't think we're talking about the same thing

Comment: Thanks :) so you're referring to the UITableViewCell's image right? Nothing to do with the tab bars? I'm thinking something like `cell.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()` in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Is this right?

Comment: It is a UITableView (or at least looks exactly like one) but it is part of the tabBar and opens when hitting 'more', so I don't have access to the UITableViewController of that view.

Comment: Nice so pretty custom huh? Are you subclassing things? I think this is where things may get too difficult, but I'll leave you with the possibility of having a global tint colour in your app using `window?.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()` in your appDelegate. That should guarantee it but override things elsewhere you don't want it to. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: No, this is not custom at all, this is the default behaviour of tabBar, if there are too many icons for the screen to display it automatically takes the rest of them and puts them in the more tab.

Comment: Wow sorry about that, I had no idea that was even a thing; I just tried it out myself. I see what you mean though. The `window?.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()` definitely works but if this is undesired then I understand. Perhaps you should consider if this is essential and if there is a better way to do what you ultimately want? My 2 cents. Good luck!